# What compounds are present in 3C273?

Tags: quasars, astrochemistry

Anyone know if we have any chemical reactions occuring in this quasar?

Comment: Do any of you use a specific library for spectrographic reduction (git link would be much appreciated if you do)

Comment: Are you working with a spectroscopy project? If so, the first step would be to ask people on the project with experience. Don't worry, everybody's learning...

Comment: I don’t really have anyone I can ask...